# Modify a xml node with spacing and quotes as attricutes

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, nodes

I am trying to access to the child node of an XML but the my first XML node has spacing and quotes as attributes.

```
 var xml = @"<Envelope xsd "http">
            <Catalog>
                <Price>
                  <Value Default ="yes">P1</Value>
                </Price>
            </Catalog>
        </Envelope>";
```

Im trying to change the attribute value of Default from "yes" to "1" but node always returns null.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/*/Catalog/Price/Value");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that is valid xml, did you perhaps mean the following

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Valid XML
            string xml = @"<Envelope xsd='http'>
                          <Catalog>
                             <Price>
                               <Value Default='yes'>P1</Value>
                            </Price>
                          </Catalog>
                         </Envelope>";
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            //Select the Value Node
            XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/*/Catalog/Price/Value");

            //Set the Default attribute to 1
            node.Attributes["Default"].Value = 1.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            //Check the output
            Console.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

            //Press enter to exit
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Just saying.

Comment: I generated the xml from an xsd. It actually looks like this
<Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" SchemaVersion="01.01.00" xmlns="http://www.ofdaxml.org/schema">

Comment: In that case just double check on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx to make sure you have all the options right.

Comment: Thanks. Marking this as answer because it gave the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx.

Use // instead of /* since // gets the root of the document

Comment: Tried that, but i guess Stewart was right. The root was not valid from the start.

Answer (score 0):

This might appear a little hardcoded but it should work:

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    Namespace ns= "http"; //set the namespace of the root node here

    //the following is where you change the value to 1

 doc.Document.Descendants(ns+"Envelope").FirstorDefault().Descendants(ns+"Catalog").Descendants(ns+"Price").FirstorDefault().Elements("Value").Attribute("Default").SetValue("1");
```

Also, the xml looks a little wrong to me, as someone mentioned, the root node needs to be corrected.